# ESLint not linting tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want ESLint to parse and check for rule violations in all `.json` files. I am able to achieve this for *almost* all `.json` files by adding `overrides` and specify `*.json` specific rules in my `.eslintrc.cjs`

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
    extends: [
      'eslint:recommended',
      'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],
    ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "warn",
          {
              "accessibility": "no-public"
          }
      ],
      "indent": [
          "error",
          4
      ],
      "linebreak-style": [
          "error",
          "unix"
      ],
      "quotes": [
          "warn",
          "single"
      ],
      "semi": [
          "error",
          "never"
      ],
      "prefer-const": [
          "warn"
      ],
      "eol-last": [
          "error",
          "always"
      ]
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ["*.json"],
            rules: {
                "quotes": [
                    "error",
                    "double"
                ],
                "indent": [
                    "error",
                    4
                ],
                "eol-last": [
                    "error",
                    "always"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

and add `.json` to my eslint settings in vscode

```json
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "typescript",
        "javascript",
        "json"
    ],
```

This does result in ESLint checking my `package.json` or `foobar.json` file, allowing me to auto-fix on ctrl+s save, *but* it completely ignores my `tsconfig.json` file. I assume something either in an extension or VSCode itself is treating `tsconfig.json` as a special file and overriding any ESLint checks on it.

How can I force ESLint to error check and auto-fix `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Please take a look into this npm package https://github.com/zeitport/eslint-plugin-json-es

Comment: ESLint if for linting JavaScript files by default. The rules it comes with only know about that language. If you want to lint other languages like JSON you will need to add plugins for that

Comment: @ChrisBarr The vscode settings.json additions I mentioned in my post do result in ESLint linting general `.json` files, like my `package.json` or `asdfkjasf.json`. It simply does not lint `tsconfig.json`. I did attempt to use a json plugin as well, (not sure if I set it up properly), and had the same result.